# How to detect text real length/visibility/overflow?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

For quality/data integrity purposes, I have to ensure all the comments in the `column C` will be visible in the printing : no hidden overflowing text. Width, height and font are fixed and word wrap activated.

So far, I set a validation with a max text length (100 characters in my case). Standard sentences and Lorem ipsum stuff fits ok in the cell, but another user found his 100 characters are partially hidden.

Indeed, a 100 of "W" do not fit in - only approx.30. But a 30 characters max text length is too short.

How can I detect the text real length or its visibility or if it is overflowing?

Any other ideas?

### Edit

- Monotype font works perfectly. But as the comment takes far more space, I prefered the second option
- I used Jean-François Corbett's trick in [How to detect values that do not fit in Excel cells, using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930743/how-to-detect-values-that-do-not-fit-in-excel-cells-using-vba) : checking if `autofit` enlarge row or column, then restoring  initial size. This way, a maximum of 3 lines of comments are accepted. The carriage return `Alt + Enter`  is also taken into account.

  ```
  'Check previous cells
  If Cell.Column = 10 Then 'check the comments column
       Hauteur_ligne = Cell.RowHeight
       Cell.EntireRow.AutoFit  
       If Cell.RowHeight > Hauteur_ligne Then
          Cell.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2 'Red for rejected comment
          Saisie_Valide = False  'Validity flag
      Else
           Cell.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3  'Green for accepted comment
      End If

      Cell.RowHeight = Hauteur_ligne
  'end of sub, alert message
  ```

Thank you so much !

Comment: It would also be dependent on font size and type. There is no unit that describes the width of a font (in a general manner) as such you would probably have to approach this differently. You could try the answer from the question [How to detect values that do not fit in Excel cells, using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930743/how-to-detect-values-that-do-not-fit-in-excel-cells-using-vba) or [How to tell if text fits in a cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732342/how-to-tell-if-text-fits-in-a-cell)

Comment: Format the cells with fixed width (monotype) fonts like `Courier-New` and then decide on the width based on your requirement. If you use any other font - the width of each of the characters are going to be different and you will face such issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any perfect answer, but a workaround may be -

- Set your validation to 100 chars
- Set the width of your comments column to fit 100 of the widest character you can find in the font you are using. Maybe it's the W character ... maybe its something else - trial and error is your friend
- Set your maximum print page width to be a maximum of 1 page. The max page length does not matter ... either leave it blank or make it large, like 999, depending on your version of Excel

This means your spreadsheet may not fit on just one screen ... your users may need to to scroll right a little ... and you may have a little more white space in your printout than you may like, but if print is your priority - as it seems to be - this should work every time.